# split a list into several lists given conditional values in scala

Tags: scala, list

Given a list such as

```
List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
```

And an additional list with values like

```
List(3, 2, 6)
```

How can I obtain a result like this:

```
List(List(1,2,3), List(4,5), List(6,7,8,9,10,11))
```

The first list is the values list and the second one states the size of the partitions to obtain as a result.

I thought about a recursive function using list.take() to get the elements I want and then list.drop before the next call but I'm unable to implement said solution. Any help would me greatly appreciated.

Comment: I apologize, I headed to a village for the past days and had no wifi there. I have now upvoted and accepted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list2.scanLeft((List.empty[Int], list1)) { 
  case ((_, remaining), i) =>  remaining.splitAt(i)
}.unzip._1.tail
```

Author credit: [How to split a list by another list in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49119404/how-to-split-a-list-by-another-list-in-scala)

Where list2 represents the list of indexes to split at and list1 is the list to split